# Uncaught TypeError: System.import is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, systemjs

This code is supposed to display a `div` containing Hello World, but instead I receive the error `Uncaught TypeError: System.import is not a function`. I'm following the getting started tutorial video for ng-book2, which contains the following code in `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Angular 2</title>

  <script src="js/traceur-runtime-0.0.90.js"></script>
  <script src="js/system-0.18.4.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular2-alpha31.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>System.import('js/app');</script>
  <hello-world></hello-world>
</body>
</html>
```

and `app.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="../lib/node_modules/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />

import {
  Component,
  View,
  bootstrap
} from 'angular2/angular2';

// Annotation section
@Component({
  selector: 'hello-world'
})
@View({
  template: '<div>Hello World</div>'
})
// Component controller
class HelloWorld {

}

bootstrap(HelloWorld);
```

and finally the current directory structure:

```
/ng2
  /js
    angular2-alpha31.js
    app.js
    app.js.map
    system-0.18.4.js
    system-0.18.4.js.map
    traceur-runtime-0.0.90.js
  index.html
```

Looking around for solutions, the [only issue that seems similar enough](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/434) states there's a problem with System's `config.js`. Except in this tutorial, the video shows this working without any hint of configuration. I should mention that this is being hosted on a remote server versus the local HTTP server used in the video.

Screenshots of the developer window:

[image: System.import is not a function]

[image: File list]

Each file shown in the above directory structure is the most current available on GitHub as of writing this. Is there a default configuration file I should be including if I'm using a remote server or am I missing something else entirely?

Comment: Does `System` load correctly? What does auto-complete in the JavaScript console show after `System`?

Comment: try this seed project, you have a running hello world from the start -> https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed

Comment: @tadman Sorry, not sure what you mean by auto-complete? In the console window below the error it shows `(anonymous function) @ (index):11`. Is there a method within the `System` object I can test to see if it's loading okay?

Comment: `System.import` should be a function if that's what you're expecting, but I don't see that in the version I'm using, just `get`, `normalize`, `register`, `registerModule` and `set`.

Comment: @tadman Odd, it's in my version as `"import":function(e,t,n){...}` (minified of course)

Comment: Cannot upvote enough. Thank you sir!

Comment: @dpsthree No problem! I moved the edit to an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After playing around with the files further, I found that Angular2 is overriding SystemJS' `System` object with its own. If `angular2.js` moved above `system.js` within the HTML, then the statement

```
<script>System.import('js/app');</script>
```

uses the correct System object.

This should not be happening, however it is an issue for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

> Uncaught TypeError: System.import is not a function

A tell tale indication that `js/system-0.18.4.js` failed to load.

Comment: Any more to go on basarat? I'm having same error message.

Comment: See what `System` is ... is it defined

Comment: I've created a separate post and posted my configs and such: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35636823/systemjs-and-karmajs-typeerror-system-import-is-not-a-function