# How to configure a bunch KarmaJS + JasmineJS + SystemJS?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner, commonjs, systemjs

The project tree -

```
/
    src/
        first-test.ts
    dest_es6/
        first-test.js
    spec/
        first-testSpec.js (import firstTest from 'first-test')
```

ts compiled to es6, I write tests in es6.
karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        hostname: 'localhost',
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: [
            'systemjs',
            'jasmine'
        ],

        plugins: [
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-systemjs',
            'karma-jasmine'
        ],

        systemjs: {
            configFile: './system.conf.js',
            serveFiles: [
                './spec/**/*Spec.js',
                './dest_es6/**/*.js'
            ],
            config: {
                transpiler: "traceur",
                paths: {
                    'traceur': '/node_modules/traceur/bin/traceur-runtime.js',
                    'es6-module-loader': '/node_modules/es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.js',
                    'systemjs': '/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js',
                }
            }
        },

        exclude: [],
        //files: [],
        //preprocessors: {},
        reporters: ['progress'],
        port: 8080,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        singleRun: false,
        concurrency: Infinity
    })
};
```

system.conf.js

```
System.config({
    "babelOptions": {
        "optional": [
            "runtime"
        ]
    },
    map: {
        'first-test': '/dest_es6/first-test.js'
    }
});
```

/spec/first-testSpec.js

```
import firstTest from 'first-test';

describe('# karma first test', function () {
    it('my first test is ...', function () {
        expect(firstTest()).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

/dest_es6/first-test.js

```
export default function firstTest(){
    return true;
}
```

Already tried a dozen methods found in Google, but to my regret nothing.
Explain or give a link to guide how best to set up the testing.

Oh yeah, almost forgot, here is what displays in the console at startup -

> ivan@pc:~/server/typescript-empty$ ./node_modules/.bin/karma start 26
>   02 2016 22:05:30.729:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open
>   http://localhost:8080/ 26 02 2016 22:05:30.768:INFO [karma]: Karma
>   v0.13.21 server started at http://localhost:8080/ 26 02 2016
>   22:05:30.789:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome 26 02 2016
>   22:05:34.002:INFO [Chrome 48.0.2564 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on
>   socket /#Vj-u3Y6v9k6KK0gbAAAA with id 9066564 Chrome 48.0.2564 (Linux
>   0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.034 secs / 0 secs)

Comment: I'm having similar issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35636823/systemjs-and-karmajs-typeerror-system-import-is-not-a-function There doesn't seem to be a whole lot of documentation or examples on this.