# System.registerDynamic is not a function Angular2

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

Getting the below mentioned error while running Angular2 application, though my app running successfully in the browser but I am getting this error in the console. I created the folder using `angular-cli` and using `webpack`, but unable to figure out where I need to look for this. Any help appreciated.

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31682483/2571926)? Seems pretty close to what you have

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin It is giving error as I am using webpack instead of systemJS as a module bundler

Comment: @swapnesh have you got any solution ?