# Angular AOT and lazy loading. TypeError: System.import is not a function

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I am using Angular 4. After AOT and run rollup in lazy module appears this error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise):TypeError: System.import is not a function

My project works fine in JIT but in AOT I could not redirect to lazy routes.
I could not understand why this error occurs.

How can I resolve this error?

Thanks.

Comment: The reason for the error is that it tries to use SystemJS for loading the lazy modules, which is not present when running in AOT. However I haven't tried this myself so I cannot tell you what alternative you should use. Upvoting your question.

Comment: Can you provide your route files

Comment: Follow this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462866/uncaught-typeerror-system-import-is-not-a-function

Comment: check your typescript version. running `npm install`should not show any mismatches between angular packages and typescript

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to give a definitive answer without knowing your project setup or even a full stack trace. Lots of old angular apps use system.js (I hate it), their own webpack configs, or the CLI (my favourite).

What I would say is that I currently get this error in an old project I am bringing forward to use the CLI.

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js 15201:15-36
System.import() is deprecated and will be removed soon. Use import() instead.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
 @ ./ClientApp/vendor.ts 11:0-23
```

This makes me think that maybe your issue is in the angular core files (a guess with no stack trace) and so you could try updating your angular core files.